# C++0x non-ambiguity of Generalized Initializers

Tags: c++11, initialization, curly-braces

I found a couple of example of the new **Initializer Syntax** using `{...}`. But the examples are quite old. I just want to cross-check -- is the current situation still as described?

In every context (especially templates), the following source fragments always are **non-ambiguous** -- no matter what `T` and `v` are.

- `T{v};` -- always constructs a temporary of type `T` and initialized it with value `v`.
- `T x{v};` -- initialized a variable `x` of type `T` with value `v`.
- `T x = {v};` -- same, because `=` is just optional here.
- `T a[] = {v};` -- initializes all elements of an array with the value `v`.
- `p = new T{v};` -- allocates an object of type `T` on the heap and initializes it with value `v`.

Therefore, it is still true, telling people *"Prefer the `{}`-syntax, and your source code will not have different meanings, depending on what `T` and `v` are"*.

Comment: This is really hard to answer as the final standard is not yet public. I tried looking at the active issues for section 8.5. and everything seems related to minor issues. So I think the answer is "yes", but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Yes, I tried to follow the discussion too. Some people must have access to the final version, though... ;-)

Comment: Keep in mind that `T a[] = {v};` is the same as `T a[1] = {v};`, which is _very_ different from `T a[2] = {v};`  (if `v` is only one value)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `T x{v};` -- initialized a variable x of type T with value v.
- `T x = {v};` -- same, because = is just optional here.

As far as N3291 (the last working draft before the final standard) is concerned, these are not the same for all possible `v` and `T`.

The principle difference is the following. The first is an explicit constructor call, and it therefore may select a constructor declared `explicit`. The second is *not* an explicit constructor call (even though it will call a constructor). Therefore it *cannot* select `explicit` constructors.

From 13.3.1.7:

> In copy-list-initialization, the candidate functions are all the constructors of T. However, if an explicit constructor is chosen, the initialization is ill-formed.

The purpose of this is to ensure that you cannot accidentally perform an `explicit` conversion of a value when using copy initialization, even with `{}` syntax.

Comment: Thanks! I missed that. I think got it from Scott Meyers slides (~1yr old) or Bjarnes (>3ys old).